# Google script google calendar TypeError: Cannot call method "createEvent" of null

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I am trying to follow the examples here in google script calendar. I didn't change the code except for the calendarID thing. The code is exactly the same as the example shows:

```
function createEvent(calendarId) {
      var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
      var title = 'Script Demo Event';
      var start = new Date("April 1, 2012 08:00:00 PDT");
      var end = new Date("April 1, 2012 10:00:00 PDT");
      var desc = 'Created using Google Apps Script';
      var loc = 'Script Center';

      var event = cal.createEvent(title, start, end, {
          description : desc,
          location : loc
      });
    };
```

I am not sure if I need to change calendarId to my 'xxxxx@gmail.com'. But when i run these code,the error is `TypeError: Cannot call method "createEvent" of null. (line 15, file "Code")`

What is the problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is telling you that there is no Calendar with this ID, the usual form of a calendar ID for a non domain user is something like  *h22xxxxxxxjb6ul4hu7ft8@group.calendar.google.com*, and for a domain : *domain.xxx_se8nmkl1qsqxxxxxxxxx28ufs@group.calendar.google.com*.[image]

Have you checked that the ID you entered is valid ?

You can also test the same script using `getCalendarsByName('calendarName')` which will return an array of all the calendars having this name in your calendars, in this case you'll have to generally pick the first one using `getCalendarsByName('calendarName')[0]`.

You can also use your default calendar using `getDefaultCalendar()`, this is the one attached to your gmail address.
All this is pretty well illustrated in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app?hl=fr-FR).

This small code will allow you to check the IDs of all the calendars you own or subscribed to.

```
function testCals(){
  var cals = CalendarApp.getAllCalendars();
  for(var n in cals){
    Logger.log(' calendar ID = '+cals[n].getId()+'\nName = '+cals[n].getName()+'\n')
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I have double check my calendarId using "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m_ph_hYT_SY", it's wierd that my calendarId is the same with my email address.as i mentioned, it doesn't work....And when i use the code you give me the log info is "0"...

Comment: What do you mean by '0' ? It just can't return a single 0, it must contain "calendar ID:  .....". Do you need some tips on how to view the Logger?  Feel free to ask.

Comment: I looked at the video, your personal calendar (AKA default calendar or gmail calendar) ID is indeed your email, that's normal...and the script you are showing works with my email in the ID field, I just tested to be sure (but why did you create this #@!!§§# event in april 2012 ?? XD) not sure what your issue is really after all, please describe thoroughly. thx

Comment: Thank you! Problem solved. THe problem is if i want to write this script as an app, i have to add a doGet() function and call createEvent.

Comment: Great! This helped a lot. But please correct: Its `getCalendarsByName` an `s` is missing in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The event in 2012 is the default code used by google as an example

Comment: Please use comments to comment... not answers. Thx