# Google Script: TypeError: Cannot call method "createEvent" of null

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-calendar-api

This is my first google script and it doesn't work. When I start this script to test it in the script editor, I get the error which stands in the title "...on line 51" which is on "var event = cal.createEvent(title, start, end, {..." . Can you give me a tip?

Is the following code ok?

```
var calendarId = "xyz@group.calendar.google.com";

 //Column containg the Start Date/Time for the event
 var startDtId = 4;
 //Column containg the End Date/Time for the event
 var endDtId = 5;
 //Column containg the First Part of the Title for the event (In this case, Name)
 var titleId = 2;
 //Column containg the Comments for the event
 var descId = 3;
 //Column containg the Time Stamp for the event (This will always be 1)
 var formTimeStampId = 1;
 //Column containg the Location
 var locId = 6;
 //Column containg more Informations
 var infosId = 7;

 function getLatestAndSubmitToCalendar() {
     //Allow access to the Spreadsheet
     var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
     var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
     var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
     var values = rows.getValues();
     var lr = rows.getLastRow();
     //Removed setting of Hour and Minute for the Start and End times as these are set in our form
     var startDt = sheet.getRange(lr, startDtId, 1, 1).getValue();
     var endDt = sheet.getRange(lr, endDtId, 1, 1).getValue();
     //Setting the Comments as the description, and addining in the Time stamp and Submision info
     var desc = "" + sheet.getRange(lr, descId, 1, 1).getValue() + "n" + subOn;
     //Create the Title using the Name and tType of Absence
     var title = sheet.getRange(lr, titleId, 1, 1).getValue() + " – " + sheet.getRange(lr, titleId2, 1, 1).getValue();
     //Setting the Location
     var loca = sheet.getRange(lr, locId, 1, 1).getValue();
     //Setting more Information
     var infos = sheet.getRange(lr, infosId, 1, 1).getValue();
     //Run the Crete event Function
     createEvent(calendarId, title, startDt, endDt, desc, loca, infos);
 };

 function createEvent(calendarId, title, startDt, endDt, desc, loca, infos) {
     var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
     var start = new Date(startDt);
     var end = new Date(endDt);
     var loc = loca;

     var event = cal.createEvent(title, start, end, {
         description: desc,
         location: loc
     });
 };
```

I read the answer in the following thread, but my calendar-id is definitely correct. Therefore I ask you in this new thread.
[Google script google calendar TypeError: Cannot call method "createEvent" of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19572231/google-script-google-calendar-typeerror-cannot-call-method-createevent-of-nul)

Comment: can you maybe ident the code? This code is so hard to read

Answer (score 0):

It means that your cal object is null, so there is something wrong in your `CalendarApp.getCalendarByID(calendarID)` row

Comment: yeah, but why? i have the correct id there...i cant find the problem :/

Comment: add a console.log(calendarId) just before that row and check if it's still correct. I don't know otherwise